# AudioKit 5 Amplitude Envelope no sound

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, envelope

I'm new here and new with music apps (and programming in general).

I'm trying to build a **synth** app using **AudioKit 5** for my final project.
I made an **oscillator** and tried to add **Amplitude Envelope** but no sound coming out.
(If I put the oscillator in the output - there is a sound.)

I saw this question in the internet several times in different types but without any solution.

Does anyone know what is the problem?
And if not - do you have other solution for envelope?

The code:

```
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit
import UIKit

class TryingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var osc = Oscillator(waveform: Table(.sine), frequency: 440, amplitude: 0.8)
    var engine = AudioEngine()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func onBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let envelope = AmplitudeEnvelope(osc)
        envelope.attackDuration = 0.1
        envelope.decayDuration = 0.01
        envelope.sustainLevel = 0.5
        envelope.releaseDuration = 0.3
        
        osc.start()
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print(error, "Field")
        }
        engine.output = envelope
        
        envelope.start()
    }
    
    @IBAction func offBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        osc.stop()
    }
    
}
```

Edit:

I add this code and it works now, thanks to Aurelius Prochazk!

```
var isGateOpend = false 
.
.
. 
if isGateOpend{ 
    envelope.closeGate() 
    isGateOpend = false 
   } else { 
    envelope.openGate() 
    isGateOpend = true 
   }
```

I still have a click, but I will open another question about it if I won't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AmplitudeEnvelope is a "Gated" Node meaning that it responds to openGate and closeGate which should be used instead of start stop since those are at the node level rather than control level.

Comment: First - thanks!
Can you please explain more and give a code example?
And you mean like "envelope.open"?
I'm really new.

Comment: Ok, I used this code and it is work but I'm still getting a digital noise (tic) when I close it.
is it because of the computer or I need to add something?

`
    var isGateOpend = false
.
.
.
if isGateOpend{
            envelope.closeGate()
            isGateOpend = false
        } else {
        envelope.openGate()
            isGateOpend = true
        }
`

Comment: With a release value of 0.3 yo should not hear a click when running envelope.closeGate().  Are you also stopping the oscillator as it looks like you are in offBtn code originally?

Comment: Even with a release value of 0.7 I still have a click, and I don't have oscillator.stop() anymore.
Do you have any idea why I still have a click? The attack works good

Comment: FWIW I pasted in your code and I don't hear a click on my system.

Comment: Solved, Thanks!
When I wrote it correctly with mvc..